# Excel VBA Removing Filter from AutoFilter actually removes all records

Tags: excel, vba

I've been having an issue trying to get this to work.
I've got the Filter working correctly, But I cannot get it to remove the filter and show all records.
What happens is that its removing all the Check-marks from the filter instead of Selecting them all, thereby leaving me with a blank Table.
I've tried multiple variations on the below, as well as simply going:

```
Sheets("live_list").Range("main_list").AutoFilter Field:=8
```

Main Code as it currently sits.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If "D2" <> "All" Then
        Sheets("live_list").Range("main_list").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 4).Value
   Else
        Sheets("live_list").ListObjects("main_list").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `"D2" <> "All"` isn't doing what you think it is btw. That's comparing the string `D2` to the string `All`. `"D2" <> "All"` will always be `True`.

Comment: Change `Sheets("live_list").ListObjects("main_list").AutoFilter.ShowAllData` to `Sheets("live_list").ShowAllData`

Comment: @BigBen Bingo, That was the Issue, I have no clue what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sheets("live_list")
        If Not .FilterMode = True Then
            .Range("main_list").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 4).Value
        Else
            .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This should work fine.

Comment: I wanted to be able to filter by whatever was put in the cell (its a validated dropdown), and then remove the filter by having the"all option"

Answer (score 0):

Was being stupid and Wasn't declaring the Cell properly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Cells(2, 4).Value <> "All" Then
        Sheets("live_list").Range("main_list").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Cells(2, 4).Value
   Else
        Sheets("live_list").ListObjects("main_list").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   End If
        
End Sub
```